# onChange="document.myform.submit() and PHP while loop

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following code and on it's own works fine, but I need to have it in a PHP while loop as there may be hundreds of records. This does not work, meaning it does not submit the form.

Any help with this code, or other ideas that will work are appreciated. It also needs to write to a mysql DB the new value. Please note that I am less than a newbie with javascript.

Thanks

```
<form action="home.php" method="post" name="status">
    <input type="hidden" name="record_number" value="<? echo $r['record_number']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="cstatus">
    <select name="statuscode" type="dropdown" style="font-size: 8pt; width: 60px" onChange="status.submit();">
        <? if($r['statuscode']) { echo "<option value='".$r['statuscode']."'>".$r['statuscode']."</option>"; } ?>
        <option value='Open'>Open</option>      
        <option value='Closed'>Closed</option>
        <option value='Pending'>Pending</option>        
        <option value='Cancelled'>Cancelled</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you rewrite the question so it actually makes sence?

Comment: Are you actually serious? If you can not figure this I would be wary of 'any' question you respond to on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

```
onChange="status.submit();"
```

Status is undefined. It sounds like you are depending on legacy Internet Explorer weirdness to create globals for any element with a name.

The quick fix is:

```
this.form.submit();
```

or, since there is an input named submit already (avoid having things named the same as existing properties, it makes a mess)

```
document.createElement('form').submit.call(this.form);
```

That said, as a UI, a drop down menu that automatically submits a form is horrible, and depending on JS is just a poor approach.

Having a submit button for each option (there are only a maximum of 5) would take up a little bit more space, but would resolve things with a single click.

```
<input type="submit" name="statuscode" value="Open">
<input type="submit" name="statuscode" value="Closed">
<input type="submit" name="statuscode" value="Pending">
<input type="submit" name="statuscode" value="Cancelled">
```

Comment: `this.status.submit();` doesn't work

Comment: Drat. That's me rushing ahead. Fixed it.

Comment: +1 for helping to stop the spread of poor IE4 Javascript.

Comment: this.form.submit(); does not work, and adding a submit button is not an option as space is already a concern.

Comment: `this.form.submit()` should work … oh. Since I didn't see a submit button in there, I didn't expect to see an input named submit. That will conflict. The simplest option is to rename it to something else. Failing that… `document.createElement('form').submit.call(this.form)` might work.

Comment: Space shouldn't be a significant problem. Browsers do have scrollbars.

Comment: This is for a customer and they don't want scroll bars if can be avoided, but your document.createElement('form').submit.call(this.form) seems to have done the trick. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly in my situation:

```html
<select ... onChange="this.form.submit();">
```